# NodeJS Reading all files in a dir by each line

Tags: node.js

I am fairly new to NodeJS, I am trying to read all files in a given dir and then print out the results line by line using the code below

```
 var fs=require('fs'),fsf = require('fs'),lazy = require('lazy');
 var fr;
 var dir = '/path/to/dir';
 fs.readdir(dir,function(err,files){
  if (err) throw err;
   files.forEach(function(file){
    console.log(file);
    fr = fsf.createReadStream(file);
      //console.log(fr);
    new lazy(fr).lines.forEach(function(line){
        console.log(line.toString());   
    });
  });
```

I am getting the following error

Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined
Any pointers will be really appreciated!

Comment: whay are you using two different kind of fs ?

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was part of the debugging to see if I get a different result. I should have removed that.

Comment: just try to write one line before `console.log`, `if (line)` see it works or not

Comment: I tried your code but I didn't get this problem, I got error `ENOENT` so I changed your `createReadStream(file) to createReadStream(dir+'/'+file)`. This could also a problem.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your response. Unfortunately even after using   createReadStream(dir+'/'+file) I still get the same issue    console.log(line.toString());
                       ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined

Comment: I use the following for a single file var lazy = require("lazy"),fs  = 'require("fs");'
  'var fr = fs.createReadStream('somefile.md');'
  'new lazy(fr).lines.forEach(function(line){'
  '  if ((line.toString().search('\\+') != -1)||(line.toString().search('@') != -1)){'
  ' console.log(line.toString()); '
  '}' and it works fine
  7 });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: - There were actually two issues

1. (main) The blank lines in the individual files were causing this
   exception.
2. The hidden files were getting picked up by the program.

Corrected both and here is the refactored code

```
var fs=require('fs'),lazy = require('lazy');
var fr;
var dir = '/path/to/dir';
fs.readdir(dir,function(err,files){    //Get a listing of all the files in the dir
  if (err) throw err;
  files.forEach(function(file){
    if(file.search('\\.md') != -1) {    //Only read markdown files
      console.log(file);
      fr = fs.createReadStream(file);
      new lazy(fr).lines.forEach(function(line){
        if (typeof line != 'undefined'){    // Skip blank lines within the files
          if ((line.toString().search('\\+') != -1)||(line.toString().search('@') != -1)){
            console.log(line.toString());
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

The code seems fine and is working with other directories and on other machines. After some investigation it seems to be an issue with the .DS_Store hidden files in the directory. I was trying this on a Mac with OSX  10.9.4. I am not 100% sure, but for now that seems to be the likely cause of the error.
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to do that, but since I answered my own question, I will need to wait for 24hrs before I can accept it.